# Haskell-function composition ((<*>) . (<*>))

Tags: haskell, function-composition

```
    ((<*>) . (<*>))
    --In GHCi
    :: (a1 -> a2 -> b) -> ((a1 -> a2) -> a1) -> (a1 -> a2) -> b
```

Why is it in such type? how can it evolve to such type?

```
    :t ((<*>) .)

    ((<*>) .)
      :: Applicative f => (a1 -> f (a2 -> b)) -> a1 -> f a2 -> f b

    :t (. (<*>))
    (. (<*>))
      :: Applicative f => ((f a -> f b) -> c) -> f (a -> b) -> c

    ((<*>) . (<*>))
    --from left to right
```

1. `(<*>) :: Applicative f1 => f1 (a1 -> b1) -> f1 a1 -> f1 b1`;
2. `(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`;
3. `(<*>) :: Applicative f2 => f2 (a2 -> b2) -> f2 a2 -> f2 b2`;

In **2.**, `(a -> b)`, let **3.** `f2 (a2 -> b2) = a`;  therefore, `b` should be `f2 a2 -> f2 b2`, `(b -> c)`, replaced by **1.**, `b` is `f1 (a1 -> b1)`, `c` should be `f1 a1 -> f1 b1`

However, `b` should be equal to each other, `f2 a2 -> f2 b2 = f1 (a1 -> b1)`  ?     how to fit both to each other
In GHCi, it seems it replaces `f (a -> b)` with `a1` or `a2`, then how it goes forward?

Comment: What dou you mean with "*Why is it in such a type*"?

Comment: Remember that `(->) a` is an `Applicative`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I know it's an Applicative, what can it help to evolve the composition?

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is correct, as far as I can see.

The next step, as you wrote, is solving

```
f2 a2 -> f2 b2 = f1 (a1 -> b1)
```

which is, in prefix notation,

```
(->) (f2 a2) (f2 b2) = f1 (a1 -> b1)
```

this means that

```
(->) (f2 a2) = f1
f2 b2 = a1 -> b1 = (->) a1 b1
```

so,

```
(->) (f2 a2) = f1
f2 = (->) a1
b2 = b1
```

I think you can continue from here. Just remember to interpret `x -> y` as `(->) x y`.

---

Exploiting the above, plus your own findings for `a` and `c`, we get:

```
a = f2 (a2 -> b2) 
  = (->) a1 (a2 -> b2)
  = a1 -> a2 -> b2
  = a1 -> a2 -> b1

c = f1 a1 -> f1 b1
  = (->) (f2 a2) a1 -> (->) (f2 a2) b1
  = (f2 a2 -> a1) -> (f2 a2 -> b1)
  = ((->) a1 a2 -> a1) -> ((->) a1 a2 -> b1)
  = ((a1 -> a2) -> a1) -> (a1 -> a2) -> b1

a -> c =
  = (a1 -> a2 -> b1) -> ((a1 -> a2) -> a1) -> (a1 -> a2) -> b1
```

which is the original type (with `b` renamed as `b1` here).

Comment: thanks for the help, so how can we do after that, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I guess there should be some theorem from mathematical side(lambda calculus) to deal with the f(a->b) and f a -> f b stuff. something like structure distributive law. I'm not sure... :-(

Comment: @CLQ0728 You just need to substitute everything. See the edit above.